# Does magnitude of difference between two variables affect the confidence level?

Tags: statistical-significance, sequential-analysis

I have two sets of data that I'm using proprietary software (TubeBuddy) to do data analysis to find which image is "better." I'm assuming the software is doing a two-sample t-test.

TubeBuddy's definition of statistical significance is where they go the most in-depth with how their software works:

> Statistical Significance is a standard mathmatical [sic] calculation that
> lets you know (based on video impressions and clicks) when one version
> of the test has a 95% (or better) chance of out-performing the other
> in the long-run [sic] (and both the Original and Variation have 500+
> impressions). The test length can be as quick as 2 days or last weeks
> depending on how many times YouTube displays it on screen and how well
> your variation CTR is performing against the original. Your video will
> automatically get set to the winning version once Statistical
> Significance is acheived [sic].

One is the conversion (as a percent) of one image design and the other is the conversion of another image design. My goal is to decide if one image converts better than another. Every day I get new data that changes both the percent difference between the two conversions and the confidence level. The testing ends and data is no longer collected once a confidence level of 95% is reached.

In some tests, I'll see a percent difference of something like 1% and some well into the 100s. I do see that those tests with a smaller percent difference seem to have to run longer than the ones where the percent difference is broad. **Are the percent difference between two variables and the confidence level directly related** or do they just appear as such in this instance?

Sample data
[image]
[image]

(It's been a while since I took a stat course, I'm sorry.)

Comment: What do you mean that the testing ends once a confidence level of 95% is reached? Do you mean that you keep collecting data until you get something like $p<0.05$ from a hypothesis test and then take that p-value as your answer?

Comment: @Dave Yes, testing ends once we're able to say we can reject Ho or we cannot reject Ho at a 94% confidence level. So each day, we run a test from the collective data up until that day. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's a huge mistake and will cause you to reject true null hypotheses way too often. I just did a quick simulation (too long for a comment) where this results in $993$ rejections of the null hypothesis in $1000$ attempts ($\alpha = 0.05$), despite the null hypothesis being true. // Do you just keep on collecting data until one p-value is sufficiently small? What happens if you never collect enough data to reject?

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure, I'm using proprietary, closed-source software (TubeBuddy A/B testing) for this and while I'm technically not reverse-engineering it, I'm trying to understand how it works because I'm curious about what's going on and I'm seeing these patterns in my daily data collection. I've done two-sample t-testing of the same data by hand and getting different results, so I'm really curious about what's under the hood.

Comment: You seems to be doing some kind of sequential analysis, which needs very special methods! Look through the tag [tag:sequential-analysis] and maybe add it to your post!